# SUM AND GROUP BY WITH LIMITED ROWS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to sum only the last 2 weeks for each user and GROUP BY User.

MY TABLE:

```
+----+------+--------+------+
| ID | User | Income | Week |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 1  | John | 50     | 1    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 2  | John | 20     | 2    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 3  | John | 25     | 3    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 4  | John | 10     | 4    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 5  | Mike | 45     | 1    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 6  | Mike | 15     | 2    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 7  | Mike | 10     | 3    |
+----+------+--------+------+
| 8  | Mike | 5      | 4    |
+----+------+--------+------+
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
+------+--------+
| User | Income |
+------+--------+
| John | 35     |
+------+--------+
| Mike | 15     |
+------+--------+
```

As you can see, I'm summarizing week 4 and 3 for each user because those are the last 2 weeks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you given it a try and then failed? What's your question?

Comment: Man, honestly I don't have an idea where to start. I tried different group by and limit. I just feel that I'm far from solving it.

Comment: Which database are you using? You have tagged both mysql and postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a row_number() to sort out the top two weeks for a given user. Thereafter, you could aggregate. Works in postgresql.

```
Select user, sum(income) 
from(
     select user, income, row_number() over (partition by user order by week desc) rn 
     from your_table
    ) 
where rn<3 group by user;
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql---

```
SELECT User,Sum(Income) as Income
FROM mytable
WHERE week > (SELECT MAX(week) FROM mytable) - 2
GROUP BY User
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf327/3)

PostgreSQL---

```
SELECT "user",Sum(Income) as Income
FROM mytable
WHERE week > (SELECT MAX(week) FROM mytable) - 2
GROUP BY "user"
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0016f/4)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that only works if the column used for ordering holds numeric values. So let say instead of ordering by week (numeric), I need to order it using an alphabetical column.

The row_number() approach works under any circumstance.

Comment: if week is char it still works in mysql. but for postgresql you'll have to cast(week as integer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mysql`, then give a row number based on group by User and in the descending order of week number. Then find the sum of income group by User and having the row number less than 3.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.User, SUM(t.Income) AS Income from(
    SELECT ID, User, Income, week,(
        CASE User WHEN @curA
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curA := User end
    ) + 1 AS row_num
    FROM my_table tbl,
    (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
    ORDER BY User, Week DESC
)t
WHERE t.row_num < 3
GROUP BY t.User
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named `users` with fields `user, income, week`:

```
SELECT user AS User, SUM( income ) AS Income FROM users WHERE week > 2 GROUP BY user
```

**OR**

```
SELECT user AS User, SUM( income ) AS Income FROM users WHERE week = 3 OR week = 4 GROUP BY user
```

If your weeks are dynamic, then you may need to calculate the where clause values.